# ZF2 override framework classes via autoloader classmap

Tags: zend-framework2

Is it possible to override the class file location of a framework class via classmap and autoloader? If yes, then how?

Example: I want to override Zend\Form\Fieldset, so that everywhere in the framework where Zend\Form\Fieldset is referenced, I want it to use my own class file instead of the original.

Motivation: When updating the framework, I want to keep my modifications safe from getting overwritten.

Known alternative: Modify the code in the framework.
Disadvantage: Modification gets lost when updating the framework.

Comment: when voting down, please add a comment so I know what I have done wrong, thank you very much, otherwise I wouldn't know and make the same mistake again :-|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

writing the same class (FQCN) at another location is generally a bad idea. This causes two classes which are equally named to live in two separate locations. It's a much better idea to create your own `Fielset` in your own namespace. Say, `Application\Form\Fieldset`.

You can extend the ZF2 fieldset by your own. Then reference this new fieldset class and its all much more maintainable.

The downside of this method is you don't automatically use the new fieldset class. You have to reference the `Application\Form` namespace in every form you use. On the other hand, this makes it much more clear to other users of you code what exactly happens: there are no unexpected consequences using ZF2 code.

The only remark I have to make here is, for what do you need another fieldset? If you think you need that for view helpers, that's not true. You can modify the view helper to render fieldsets without modifying the Fieldset form class itself.

Comment: Thanks! The reason for this is, I want my fieldsets rendered in the order as I add them to the form, that is in sequence with the normal elements. The default behaviour of a fieldset (and thus also a form) is that the fieldsets are separated from the other elements at the end of the function add(). So when rendering, I can't see how to mix them together in the right order as specified again. So I think I'm better off by adding the fieldsets to the elements array instead of the fieldsets array. I don't know yet what detrimental side effects my workaround could have, I guess there will be some.

Comment: There will be, but you'll find out I guess :) Makes sense that you need your own Fieldset object. Just reference to your own one, that's much easier that trying to override an existing class.